# Do I need to join a multicast group before writing to it?

Tags: network-programming, multicast

Say I have a process that only produces messages, it is not interested in receiving messages from other group members. Does it really need to join the multicast group before writing to it?

*I can imagine scenarios where it depends on the multicast routing protocol being used... but if you have details that would be great.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't. Joining the group is only required for reading it.